# How to calculate Non Uniform value percentage from Range in table?

Tags: python

For example: when a bottle of water is fully filled, it is 100%, 50% in half, and 0% in empty. I want to calculate that how many liters does this tank have when it is 100% full if its Non uniform value ?
Example table:

```
Data              %
------         -------
150 (L)          100 %
120 (L)          90 %
90  (L)          70%
10  (l)          20 %
```

This is sample data. Suppose i received value from Server and the value is 130(L). I want to measure that, how many percentage fuel in my tank based on this value?

Comment: Actually i want to calculate value (L) to percentage that already i mentioned in to table.

Comment: You just need to divide the current volume by the percentage full (converted to a fraction) to get the full tank volume. For example, 120 liters / 0.9 = 133.33 liters full volume. You are just solving the algebra problem (fraction full) = (current volume) / (full volume), trying to find (full volume) when you know the other two parts => (full volume) = (current volume) / (fraction full).